# Dropping rows but adding columns to the dropped rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a issue with a CSV data frame. There is two parts to this process,

The first part is, where I get a Colum which is an empty string, I want to drop the entire row.

The second part, I create a csv and add in some rows, pre populated with a string of text.

The issues I'm getting is, I'm dropping the empty rows ok, but then in still adding the strings to the dropped rows? Any idea's why this is happening?

```
#Drops any empty strings
def drop_empty():
    for i in df.index:
        if type(df.loc[i, 'ABC']) == '':
            df.drop(i, inplace=True)


def make_csv():
    # Creates the CSV file with a datetime with no index, and adds the map, collection and collection address to the CSV
    df['Map'] = 'MAP'
    df['Asset collection'] = 'Distribution'
    df['Asset collection address 1'] = 'Distribution'
    df['Asset collection address 2'] = 'Units1+2'
    df['Asset collection address 3'] = 'ind Est'
    df['Asset collection city'] = 'Coventry'
    df['Asset collection postcode'] = 'ABC DFG'
    df.to_csv('Clean_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), index=False, quotechar='"', sep=',')
drop_empty()
make_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
def drop_empty():
    idxs = []
    for i in df.index:
        if df.loc[i, 'ABC'] != '':
            idxs.append(i)
    return df.reindex(idxs)


def make_csv():
    # Creates the CSV file with a datetime with no index, and adds the map, collection and collection address to the CSV
    df['Map'] = 'MAP'
    df['Asset collection'] = 'Distribution'
    df['Asset collection address 1'] = 'Distribution'
    df['Asset collection address 2'] = 'Units1+2'
    df['Asset collection address 3'] = 'ind Est'
    df['Asset collection city'] = 'Coventry'
    df['Asset collection postcode'] = 'ABC DFG'
    df.to_csv('Clean_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), index=False, quotechar='"', sep=',')
df = drop_empty()
make_csv()
```

Get rid of the `type(..)`.

Comment: So doing that and I'm still getting my dropped rows where my nan's where, but its still applying my second function to the removed fields? Should i send you some test data?

Comment: Tried your solution and my strings are still coming through from the removed rows.

Comment: Still no dice, do you want a test data set?